# How to fix "error: cannot create ngrok Permission denied" in mac?

Tags: macos, localhost, ngrok

I am new to mac and bit confused about file structure .I am trying to download and access ngrok from my mac .I used below command to unzip the ngrok zip file

**`unzip /Users/apocha/Downloads/ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip`**

but getting below error:

```
Archive:  /Users/apocha/Downloads/ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip
error:  cannot create ngrok
        Permission denied
```

> This is folder where I have ngrok zip file ***/Users/apocha/Downloads***

Can someone help me fix this issue ?

I tried changing permissions of the file using below command ,

> **chmod -x ngrok**

but got error

```
chmod: ngrok: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Apoorva you can also use the UI to unzip the file, should be possible to unzip by double click it when viewing the file with Finder app...

Otherwise, just tested it on command line, `cd ~/Downloads` and then `unzip ./ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip` should also work.

Seems odd there are no permissions in your own downloads folder, but the last command `chmod -x ngrok` should also reference the exact filename and not "ngrok" if you want to change permissions for that file.